# Loading a file in vim via piped output of ag

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I feel as if my scenario is fairly simple but that I might be overcomplicating it.

I am searching through files looking for a special condition, that is where the method `.all` with arguments exists.  In the real world that looks like:

```
ba_mbn_programs = Program.ba_and_managed_bar.all(:conditions => "user_programs.user_id = #{current_user.id} and brand_id = #{brand.id}", :order => :name, :joins => [:user_programs], :select => "distinct programs.*")
```

I'm able to find those using ag like this:

```
ag '\.all\(.*\)'
```

That gives me a big list of file names and line numbers (here's a snippet):

```
lib/ui_elements.rb
4:      self.active.all(:select => ["name, #{model}.id"], :order => :name).collect{|m| [m.name, m.id]}.insert(0, ["All", nil])
```

So in no particular order, I need to address these lines in my editor.  So what I really want to do is open up the file `lib/ui_elements.rb` in vim and go right to line 4.

I've learned that using `vim +line_num file_name` is a way to do that.  However just isolating the line number and file name from the ag output has forced me to do something like this:

```
vim `ag '\.where\(.*\)' app | tail -1 | sed -E 's/([^:]*):([0-9]*):.*/\1 \2/' | awk -v q="+" '{print q $2, $1}'`
```

So that just reads the last file from that search and opens the file in vim to that line number.  Surely there is a better way then this?

Comment: Why not just use the `:grep` command from within Vim? Perhaps what you need is a Vim skill (consult [vi.se]) rather than a code review.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the `vim` call like this:

```
vim $(ag '\.where\(.*\)' app | sed -nE '$s/([^:]*):([0-9]*):.*/+\2 \1/p')
```

That is, no need for the `awk` to print the matched filename and line number in reverse, you can reverse in the `sed`, and also prefix the number with `+` there.

I dropped the `tail -1`, by using the `-n` flag of `sed` to not print output by default, added `$` in front of the `s///` command to apply for only the last line of input, and the `/p` flag to print after substitution.
Although this has the benefit of eliminating a `tail` process in the middle, it has the disadvantage that it's a bit harder to understand. So you can put back `tail -n 1` (more portable than `tail -1`) if you prefer.

I also changed the obsolete `` `...` `` to `$(...)`.